Pyinstaller cannot detect C-module in package
I'm using Pyinstaller to create a Windows executable from Python code.
My Python script depends on a package called MT5Manager, which is compiled from C.
I can use python main.py to run the script without error, but when I try running the .exe file, I get an error that says:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 5, in <module>
    manager = MT5Manager.ManagerAPI()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SystemError: <class 'MT5Manager.ManagerAPI'> returned NULL without setting an exception
[6680] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!

Here is what I did, step by step:

Create an virtualenv

python -m venv .venv
.venv\Script\activate


Install package from pypi:

pip install MT5Manager pyinstaller


create a main.py with content as follows:

import numpy # I use this because I don't want to use --hidden-import in pyinstaller command
import MT5Manager

print("Prepair")
manager = MT5Manager.ManagerAPI()
print("OK.")


create an executable file:

pyinstaller -F main.py --paths .venv\Lib\site-packages

I'm using PyInstaller version 6.6.0 on Windows 11, using Python 3.12.3 provided by pyenv-win.
What is wrong, and how can I fix it?

That's not just a "C-module" in package because it requires an additional step to load the actual .dll (via __file__) which may not be compatible with pyinstaller's file inclusion detection. Check first to see if the generated archive whether or not it include the affected .dll, and see if manually including that may fix the issue.

@metatoaster. Your comment put me on the right way, the problem was solved by adding the parameter --add-binary .venv\Lib\site-packages\MT5Manager\MT5APIManager64.dll:. or more specific is --add-data .venv\Lib\site-packages\MT5Manager:. when run the pyinstaller command. Would you like to add an answer?

Not really, because this is a fairly common issue with PyInstaller so that linked QnA is technically is the answer already. You are free to add your own self-answer if you want.
